# application get crash when installed in ios9 device and conpiled from xcode6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, xcode7

i had application which get crash if it create build from xcode6.1 and install in my ios 9 application.

the same application if i try to create build from xcode7.
1)app below is plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

2)Bitcode in build setting as 'NO'

It work properly.
I want to create the build from xcode 6.1 what setting should i have to do in xcode such that the build work proper in ios9

**EDITTED QUESTION :-**

Step 1:- Compile code from xcode6.Create the ipa file install in two device

1 device :- ios 8 := work fine

2 device :- ios 9 :- Crash in one screen (not getting any crash).

The screen  just call one api and display the text in uitableview. nothing else.

Step 2:- Compile code from xcode7. by doing above step in build setting and plist.Create the ipa file install in two device.

1 device :- ios 8 := work fine

2 device :- ios 9 :- work fine

Please help me. What should i do change in xcode 6 (build setting and plist )files such that it work.

Because there is no issue in the code for the crash from the above scenario.

Comment: what is the crash message?

Comment: Can you also elaborate on why you want to user Xcode 6.1?

Comment: @rckoenes. I just want to find out the root cause that without doing any change in code and modifying only plist and build setting file it allow be to execute the ipa without crash.

Comment: Well if you apps crash you would be able to find the crash report otherwise there is nothing to give you a hint on what is going on. If you do not see any crash of stack trace in Xcode check the device manager for crash logs.

Answer (score 0):

Use this hope it will help you , In  .plist add it for Transport Security.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
   <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
   <true/>
</dict>
```